# Problems importing an Eclipse project into Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, build.gradle

I created my first Android app 2 years ago in Eclipse and now I have some time to improve it. I do not have Eclipse installed anymore, so I decided to import the project into Android Studio.

But now I am running into several problems:

> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 8 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0]

So in the build.gradle I changed it to 14. Then I got the next error

> Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.

So therefor I changed the `compileSdkVersion` and the `targetSdkVersion` to 25 (correct me if it's wrong). And I changed

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
```

into

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
```

Now I could build my project. But when I tried to run my app, after more then 5 minutes(!) I got the next error :

> Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
>   Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

So then I added

```
multiDexEnabled true
```

and

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

and

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

to the manifest file.

My build.gradle now looks like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<<myApplicationId>>"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
    compile files('libs/AppFireworks.jar')
    compile files('libs/fcvtgzwtzuliivdcu.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

But now I got the following pop-up and errors

> Instant Run does not support deploying build variants with multidex enabled, to a target with API level 20 or below. To use Instant Run with a multidex enabled build variant, deploy to a target with API level 21 or higher.
>
> Error:UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
>
> Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

What have I done wrong? Do I have to change the `minSdkVersion` to 21? I want to be able to run my app on Android 4.x. I could when I was developing in Eclipse. So far switching from Eclipse to Andriod Studio is going from bad to worse. :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are compiling using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`

play service is itself is a large library. You should not use `+` which implies all available version to compile

Rather use a specific version of play services or break down the library and use specific services like `location`,`maps` etc.

Also u can use `dexOptions` to increase ur memory usage during compilation

try changing your gradle file to:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "<<myApplicationId>>"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

     dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.1'
    compile files('libs/AppFireworks.jar')
    compile files('libs/fcvtgzwtzuliivdcu.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Thanks 007, I am getting there. When I used your gradle file, at least the app started. But building still took some time. So I read something about the play-services API's. I don't know why I need them. When I removed them all, I got an error about android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" in my debug/AndroidManifest.xml. Do I need that, and if so, which API should I use to compile?

Comment: Nope, not that I'm aware of. I just tried a random API from your list. It compiles when I use the plus API and also when I use the gcm API (the others I just didn't try). So the most basic API will suffice, I think. But which one is the most basic API?

Comment: most used in-- `maps` and `location` apis. u can know more about the apis here https://developers.google.com/android/